# displaying sub-menu's on hover problems

Tags: html, css, menu

I have 2 separate menu's. I want to display the links within menu #2 when hovering over certain buttons on Menu #1. I want to try and do this with CSS if possible. Some of the css I am using is below.

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.xecforce.com">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FORUMS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">GAMES</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">XECOM</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div id="sub-menu-items">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Test 2</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#sub-menu-items ul li {
list-style-type: none;
z-index: 99999;
margin-right: 15px;
padding-bottom: 8px;
padding-top: 8px;
display: none;
text-shadow: 2px 3px 3px #080808; 
}

nav ul li:first-child:hover #sub-menu-items ul li {
display: inline;
}
```

how is this not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sub-menu-items need to be a child of the li you are hovering.  Thats what this selector means:

```
nav ul li:first-child:hover #sub-menu-items ul li
```

CSS drop down menus are done like this:

HTML

```
<ul>
<li>Parent Item
    <ul>
       <li>Sub item</li>
       <li>Sub item</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Parent Item
    <ul>
       <li>Sub item</li>
       <li>Sub item</li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul ul {
display: none;
}

ul > li:hover ul {
display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to nest the sub-menus within parent 'li'
Your code will be something like this:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="parent-menu">
        <li><a href="http://www.xecforce.com">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">NEWS</a>
           <ul class="sub-menu">
             <li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Test 2</a></li>
           </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">FORUMS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">GAMES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">XECOM</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Then you can style sub-menu ul & li (preferably position:absolute) and css can be:
.parent-menu li:hover .sub-menu { display:block}

Answer (score 0):

The ':hover' state of an element can only affect its child elements. To make use of :hover to affect external elements you can make use of javascript.

The CSS in this line

```
nav ul li:first-child:hover #sub-menu-items ul li {display: inline;}
```

is looking for "#sub-menu-items ul li" inside the first "li" of "nav".

Depending on your layout you can achieve the desired effect only if you move the second menu inside the first menu.